# Any disadvantage of plist?

Tags: windows, macos

According to [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Registry#Criticism), the disadvantages of registry:

1. Installers and uninstallers become more complex.
2. A damaged System registry can stop device drivers from loading.
3. The parts of the registry may have to be kept in sync with the file system.
4. Unsuitable for use on portable devices used to carry applications from one system to another.
5. Interdependencies between applications and system components.

Property list is closest thing to registry in Mac OS:

- Key-Value storage.
- System configuration: /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.*.plist
- /user/Library/Application Support/.../*.plist

In Mac OS, users usually uninstall applications by just dragging the application to the trash con. Like Windows, it should also cause lots of useless proper lists in system?

And why plist's disadvantage is not so emphasized? (compared to registry)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's true that trashing an app will probably leave a plist file around, but they tend to be small files, so it's not a big deal.  Concerning your point (2), the advantage of plist files is that they are separate files, so if one gets damaged, it only affects the one app.